# How can I view only films without ratings on Goodfilms?

Tags: goodfilms

I'm using [Goodfil.ms](https://goodfil.ms/). I've rated many films and now have a problem finding new films that I've already watched but haven't rated yet.

Is there any way to show only unrated (by you) films and movies on [Goodfil.ms](https://goodfil.ms/)?